# Firebase extract name of object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple question today.

I retrieve data from my firebase database:

```
const response = await fetch('For pricacy purpose I replaced this link to my firebase database.');
        const resData = await response.json();
        console.log(resData);
```

Also I log the results in the console, the following text is what I retrieve:

> ```
> Object {
>   "-MPOg49jvG-md0twgj-D": Object {
>     "id": 1,
>   },
>   "-MPTgHoTXzIcY_KpBHkc": Object {
>     "id": 2,
>   },
>   "-MPTgmANDZkMv7f_A9TG": Object {
>     "id": 4,
>   },
>   "-MPTgmc2fuu5XSUawuW7": Object {
>     "id": 3,
>   },
> }
> ```

Now my question: I want to access not the id that is in the objects but rather the "name" of the object itself. If you look at the first element:

> "-MPOg49jvG-md0twgj-D": Object {
> "id": 1,   }

i want to access this "-MPOg49jvG-md0twgj-D" and store it in a constant but I dont know how to do it. Any idea would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you already fetched `resData` as a JavaScript object and want to get the keys? These are some ways that possibly could help you.

```js
const resData = {
  "-MPOg49jvG-md0twgj-D": {
    id: 1
  },
  "-MPTgHoTXzIcY_KpBHkc": {
    id: 2
  },
  "-MPTgmANDZkMv7f_A9TG": {
    id: 4
  },
  "-MPTgmc2fuu5XSUawuW7": {
    id: 3
  }
};

// method 1
console.log(Object.keys(resData));

// method 2
for (const key in resData) {
  console.log(key, resData[key]);
}

// method 3
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(resData));
```

Hope this can help, please correct me if I got it wrong.

Comment: Method 2 with the keyword "key" worked for me, I got the plain string out of resData with the object names. Thank you very much friend!